# android marshmallow app crash large arrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, android-6.0-marshmallow

Have an application that generates an arrayList of data collected from a rest call.  The arrayList is used in an adapter supporting a listView.  Had a case where the arrayList reach a size of 999 entries.

The application passes the arrayList via a putExtra on an Intent. The arrayList is used to populate a listView.  When startActivity is called, the application crashes without generating a stack trace recorded in stacktrace.

Is there a limit to the size an arrayList can be?  Have set a debug break point in the activity started and the crash is occurring right after calling the super onCreate method.

Ideas on how to debug this?  Have been able to pass a 390 entry arrayList without crashing.

Comment: "When startActivity is called, the application crashes without generating a stack trace recorded in stacktrace" -- then how do you know that your app crashed? "Is there a limit to the size an arrayList can be?" -- the entire `Intent` has to be well under 1MB. Passing a large `ArrayList` via `Intent` extras is not a good plan. "Have set a debug break point in the activity started and the crash is occurring right after calling the super onCreate method" -- try running the app outside the debugger, to allow the stack trace to reach LogCat.

Comment: Thanks.  I know the application has crashed because it's GUI presentation goes away.  Have run the application in non debug mode and still do not get a stack trace.  Will check into the possibility of exceeding the 1 mb limit.

Comment: "because it's GUI presentation goes away" -- that is not usually the symptom of a crash, though it depends a bit on how your app is written. If you are using Android Studio, switch to "No Filters" in LogCat (instead of filtering based on the app), and look for a stack trace.

Comment: The application is written to keep the gui in the foreground until dismissed by the user.  Will dump the logcat without greping for the application name.

Comment: I faced this issue recently, you should get a message like "BINDER TRANSACTION FAILED" or something similar, which meaning it was unsuccessful in the marshalling/demarshalling process - commom cause transaction too big. A REASONABLE, solution would be to break the ArrayList into parts, and marshal/dwmarshal them. On the receiving side keep adding to a new array list until it is completed. You could add a unique information, how many bundle parts, so you know when ArrayList is complete, and a bundle id. This worked for me, if you really don't want a permanent storage mechanism could be viable.

Answer (score 0):

AS @CommonsWare said, **there's a limit of < 1MB** but in real practice is way less than that, as soon as you need to pass more data than a couple hundred KBs you need to use other procedures to pass the data around.

The most common one would be to save it into a **Local database or other type of storage** and then on the other activity query for the data (on the intent you only pass the data needed to query for the list later on) and instead of loading all of them at once, you use a **CursorLoader** so that you only load the data as you need.

Other **quick and dirty** way is by adding an **static field** to pass the data to the other activity and then on load read the value and remove it, the problem that you will face is that this is **not Thread-safe** nor it will solve the issue of what to do with the data on the other activity when onSavedInstanceState gets exectued, because you are going to run into the same 1MB issue. [**WARNING:** This is the worst solution you could think of, so, please try anything else before you try this one, that's why i gave you first a very good approach and leaved this one at the end]

**[UPDATE:]**

BTW the first approach is how we fixed this problem on the Microsoft Band app, because we had so much data coming as part of a very long run (GPS points, and other tracked data). Just make sure that the data is not big enough that you will generate a bottleneck somewhere else, we used to only cache it in memory and never send it to disk to avoid the serialization process or the time it took to save and retrieve from storage.

Comment: Appreciate it but consider the use of statics to be a very poor design choice.  Will look into other approaches.

Comment: The OP is already struggling with the way his app is designed, from a coding point of view. Maybe drop the part of using a static ArrayList, as this in the long run will just  cause more issues than it solves.

Comment: @T.Barrett as i said on the response, is a very quick and dirty approach, and i just add it here because i remember seeing a Google woman giving this alternative to pass big images from activity to activity. But, i also think it should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: @MarkKeen I know and i get it, but, as i reply to Barret, i just add it because it has been in the past given by google people to solve passing big images across activities. But, you are right it should be avoided at all cost, that's why my update focuses on the first one as the more viable solution.